# SQL Query result is wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view (A) which contains 9 rows when running the following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE card_num_full is null OR card_num_full LIKE ''
```

Table B does not contain these 9 rows, so why when running the following query , I'm still getting 9 rows as a result?

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE card_num_full is null OR card_num_full LIKE ''
      AND field_1 IN   
        (SELECT field_1
         FROM B)
```

Comment: the result is never wrong. the querys are :)

Comment: @NicoRiff LOL! correct. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: JohnHC answer is right

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but note that table B doesn't have to have *nine* matching rows.  It only has to contain *one* value that matches the value of field_1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bracket your `or`

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
WHERE (card_num_full is null 
    or card_num_full like '')
and field_1 in (select field_1 from B)
```

Comment: so simple..so sad...10x
I'll accept it as answer in 8 minutes. can't do that sooner

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ISNULL()` function, then no brackets needed.

```
SELECT * 
FROM A WHERE isnull(card_num_full,'') like ''  
    and field_1 in
        (select field_1 from B)
```